# Indexing with [Int] and [[String]] Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, indexing, int

I have in index `[Int]` and `[[String]]`, now I only want to keep the `[String]` which correspond to the index:

`[0,1,4]` and `[[a,a,a],[b,b,b],[c,c,c],[d,d,d],[e,e,e],[f,f,f]]`

would give `[[a,a,a],[b,b,b],[e,e,e]]`

So `[Int] -> [[String]] -> [[String]]`

How could I do this?

I have tried `map (!!) (x y)`

where x is the [[String]] and y is the [Int]

Comment: Please show your own attempt. Explain what does not work, etc.

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
foo :: [Int] -> [[String]] -> [[String]]
foo indices strings = map (strings !!) indices
```

The type can also be generalized to

```
foo :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
```

since we don't need a list-of-lists.

This is not terribly efficient. It can be greatly improved if we can assume that the indices are increasing, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I guess using list comprehensions is an expressive way for this job.

```
getStrings :: [Int] -> [[String]] ->  [[String]]
getStrings is css = [cs | (ix,cs) <- zip [0..] css, ix `elem` is]

*Main> gs [0,1,4] [["a","a","a"],["b","b","b"],["c","c","c"],["d","d","d"],["e","e","e"],["f","f","f"]]
[["a","a","a"],["b","b","b"],["e","e","e"]]
```

So as per @Centril's comment, that i have to agree here is a monadic version of the same thing;

```
gs :: [Int] -> [[String]] ->  [[String]]
gs is css = zip [0..] css >>= \(ix,cs) -> guard (ix `elem` is) >> return cs

*Main> gs [0,1,4] [["a","a","a"],["b","b","b"],["c","c","c"],["d","d","d"],["e","e","e"],["f","f","f"]]
[["a","a","a"],["b","b","b"],["e","e","e"]]
```

Comment: I'd argue against using list comprehensions - it is not very idiomatic Haskell since it is not compositional. Use `map, filter, fold, >>=` combinators instead.

Comment: @Centril I'd argue it's not always prudent to maximise compositionality. List comprehensions tend to be very intuitive to understand. Sometimes Python's ideals are better than Haskell's, even when writing Haskell...

Comment: In particular, I don't find that monadic solution at all sensible here – it's longer, more convoluted, and not really more compositional at all. A better way of writing this without list comprehensions would be ``getStrings is = map snd . filter ((`elem`is).fst) . zip [0..]``.